# why setting the HeaderText programatically won't work?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Do any of you know why this won't work?

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText='<%=Lang.GetString("ManCan_Descripcion")%>' DataField="OcdObs" />
```

It's like the server is ignoring the <%%> tags, the page gets rendered like this:

```
<th scope="col"><%=Lang.GetString("ManCan_Descripcion")%></th>
```

Answer (score 1):

`runat="server"` missing for the control?

Edit: Wait, aren't you supposed to use the `<%#` delimiter syntax instead?

I've never used that kind of binding so I'm not 100% sure here.

Comment: If I do that it shows me this error: Error 1 Literal content ('<asp:BoundField HeaderText="') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.